# How is The Published Runway Touchdown Zone Elevation Decided?

Tags: runways, altitude, airport-markings

The touchdown zone of a runway can be up to 3,000 feet long if the information I have is accurate.

How is the published Touchdown Zone Elevation determined?  Is it the center, an average of the elevation of the entire touchdown zone, or something else?

Comment: Per the AIM it is the highest point in the first 3,000’ of the runway.

Comment: @JScarry Looks like an answer, not a comment.